# Abstract out two nearly identical methods which differ only in which property they use on an List of Objects

Tags: c#

I have two separate methods, where the meat of the method is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(FooItem I in inventory) 
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1}…", i.Name, i.Volume);
}

File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString();
```

So the in one method I have i.Volume, in another it is i.Price.  The ONLY difference between the two methods are the property of the object in the list that is being used to output.

So the question is how can I abstract this out where I can tell it which property I want to use in from the given caller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other ways of doing this. However, you could use a `Func<T,U>`

Basically every time you call `getProp(item)`, it will ask for what you passed in the *lambda expression*`

```
private void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<Inventory> source, Func<Inventory,T> getProp)
{
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(var item in source) 
   {
      sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1}…", item.Name, getProp(item));
   }

   File.WriteAllText(filename, sb.ToString());    
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<Inventory>();

...

SomeMethod(list, x => x.Volume);
SomeMethod(list, x => x.Price);
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Func Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Encapsulates a method that has one parameter and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to abstract them, just write one by one using LINQ, usually we don't abstract one-line codes.

```
var volumeOutput = string.Join("...", volumnObjects.Select(x => $"{x.Name},{x.Volumn}"));
var priceOutput = string.Join("...", priceObjects.Select(x => $"{x.Name},{x.Price}"));
```

The only difference is your original program has "..." after the last item, I don't know if it's what you want.

Comment: This is slick, and I would go with it, but I have a number of lines of code above and below the segment I gave that are also to be refactored into the method.  Will keep this in mind though for other things I have.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said i assume you already have a predefined way of choosing which property to write for a given object.Making this assumption :

```
class FooItem
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public double Volume{get;set;}
}
public void WriteFoos(IEnumerable<(string,FooItem)>inventory,string fileName){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var item in inventory) {
        WriteFoo(item,sb);
    }
    File.WriteAllText(fileName,sb);
}
public void WriteFoo((FooItem item,string property)pair,StringBuilder sb){
      object value=ChooseProperty(pair);
      sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1}", pair.property,value);
}
public object ChooseProperty((FooItem item,string property)pair){
    switch(property){
        case "Volume":return pair.item.Volume;
        case "Name":return pair.item.Name;
    }
}
```

**P.S** Choosing the property based on a given `string` with a `switch-case` is the most easy way.If you want something generic (without having to write the `switch-case` you can change the `ChooseProperty` using `System.Reflection` like:

```
public object ChooseProperty((FooItem item,string property)pair){
    PropertyInfo prop=pair.item.GetType().GetProperty(pair.property);
    object value=prop.GetValue(item);
    return value;
}
```

This however will cause you a performance hit.Another variant is to use [System.Linq.Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=netcore-2.2)